# Near-Neighbor Searching in Ternary Search Tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, nearest-neighbor, neighbours, ternary-search-tree

How is the search for the nearest neighbors in the tree? Trying to find information, I get only some formulas without illustrative examples.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3v8n.png)

Example of a function:

```
void nearsearch(Tptr p, char *s, int d) 
{   if (!p || d < 0) return; 
    if (d > 0 || *s < p->splitchar) 
        nearsearch(p->lokid, s, d); 
    if (p->splitchar == 0) { 
       if ((int) strlen(s) <= d) 
          srcharr[srchtop++] = (char *) p->eqkid; 
    } else
       nearsearch(p->eqkid, *s ? s+1:s, 
          (*s == p->splitchar) ? d:d-1); 
    if (d > 0 || *s > p->splitchar) 
        nearsearch(p->hikid, s, d); 
}
```

Comment: What is your _exact_ question?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You will have to define certain words like, _"nearest neighbor"_, try giving certain examples, like what you give input to code, and what you want as output.